How to refresh via bindingsource in DatagridView in the main form when updating in other forms without closed or not in VB.NET
I'm Trying to refresh via bindingsource in DatagridView in the main form when updating in other forms without closed or not in VB.NET
Please Guide me
Thanks
Code in autocompledatagridview (Form main)
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class autocompledatagridview
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, ProductFinaltesting)
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
            ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
      sender As Object,
      e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
      DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
       Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key As String

            If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
                Dim p = dictProducts.Values.
                FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ProductName.
                Equals(e.FormattedValue.
                ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                If p IsNot Nothing Then
                    key = p.ToString()
                Else
                    key = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
                End If
            Else
                key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
           Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                boundItem.Prp = Nothing
                boundItem.Prs = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRP").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRS").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit And p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp And p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)
                End If

                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit And p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp And p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)
                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
            End If

    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                    BindingSource1.AddNew()
                End If
            Else
            End If
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm As New formproduct
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ProductFinaltesting
    '<Browsable(False)>
    'Public Property Font As String = "☑️"
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Prp As Integer
    Public Property Prs As Integer
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName}"
    End Function

End Class
Public Class ProductFinaltestingService
    Private Shared Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test04102024.accdb;
                    Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    ' ...
    Friend Shared Function GetDistinctProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Friend Shared Function GetProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdateProducts(ByVal Obj As ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "UPDATE Products Set Unit=@Unit,Prp=@Prp,Prs=@Prs WHERE ProductName=@ProductName;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql, New With {
    Key Obj.Unit,
    Key Obj.Prp,
    Key Obj.Prs,
    Key Obj.ProductName
})
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Code in formproduct (another form)
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class formproduct
    Dim ProductFinaltestingService As New ProductFinaltestingService()
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing

    Private Sub formproduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        loaddata()
    End Sub
    Private Sub loaddata()
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)(CType(ProductFinaltestingService.GetProducts(), IList(Of ProductFinaltesting)))}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSELECT() As ProductFinaltesting
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting))
    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            txtProductname.Text = SelectDgv.ProductName
            txtUnit.Text = SelectDgv.Unit
            txtPrp.Text = CType(SelectDgv.Prp, String)
            txtPrs.Text = CType(SelectDgv.Prs, String)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Try
            Dim Prp As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(txtPrp.Text, Prp)
        Dim Prs As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(txtPrs.Text, Prs)
            ProductFinaltestingService.UpdateProducts(New ProductFinaltesting() With {
                .Unit = txtUnit.Text,
                .Prp = Prp,
                .Prs = Prs,
                .ProductName = txtProductname.Text
                    })

            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
            loaddata()
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

I attached the code result in the gif file in the file, you can see that the main form has no update or refresh when I update in another form

RESULT CODE ANSWER FROM @djv

update code full (ProductName is the primary key)
DataGridView in mainform reflect when I do an update in the product form but try to call the same productname in the new row the value that appears in the prp is still the old one
Code In formproduct
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class formproduct
    Dim ProductFinaltestingService As New ProductFinaltestingService()
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private selectedOrder As String
    Private selectedIndex As Integer
    Public Event Updated(sender As Object, e As UpdatedEventArgs)
    Public Class UpdatedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Public ReadOnly Property Unit As String
        Public ReadOnly Property ProductName As String
        Public ReadOnly Property Prp As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Property Prs As Integer
        Public Sub New(unit As String, productName As String, prp As Integer, prs As Integer)
            Me.Unit = unit
            Me.ProductName = productName
            Me.Prp = prp
            Me.Prs = prs
        End Sub
    End Class
    Private Sub OnUpdated(e As UpdatedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Updated(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub formproduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            loaddata()
        End Sub
        Private Sub loaddata()
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)(CType(ProductFinaltestingService.GetProducts(), IList(Of ProductFinaltesting)))}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSELECT() As ProductFinaltesting
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting))
    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            txtProductname.Text = SelectDgv.ProductName
            txtUnit.Text = SelectDgv.Unit
            txtPrp.Text = CType(SelectDgv.Prp, String)
            txtPrs.Text = CType(SelectDgv.Prs, String)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Try
            Dim bs = TryCast(BindingSource1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting))
            Dim Prp As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(txtPrp.Text, Prp)
            Dim Prs As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(txtPrs.Text, Prs)
            ProductFinaltestingService.UpdateProducts(New ProductFinaltesting() With {
                .Unit = txtUnit.Text,
                .Prp = Prp,
                .Prs = Prs,
                .ProductName = txtProductname.Text
                    })

            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
 ProductFinaltestingService.GetProducts.ToList().ForEach(Sub(m)
            For i As Integer = 0 To bs.Count() - 1
            If bs(i).ProductName = m.ProductName Then
            bs(i) = m
            End If
            Next i
            End Sub)

            OnUpdated(New UpdatedEventArgs(txtUnit.Text, txtProductname.Text, Prp, Prs))
   Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
  Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrder) _
            AndAlso (e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.Reset)) Then
            If (BindingSource1.List.Count > 0) Then
                selectedIndex = BindingSource1.Find("ProductName", selectedOrder)
                If (selectedIndex <= 0) Then
                    selectedIndex = 0
                End If

                DataGridView1.Rows(selectedIndex).Selected = True
            Else
                selectedOrder = String.Empty
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
End Class


Code in autocompledatagridview (MainForm)
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class autocompledatagridview
    Inherits Form
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, ProductFinaltesting)
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        updateDataSource()

    End Sub
    Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
    ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
      sender As Object,
      e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
      DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
       Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key As String

            If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
                Dim p = dictProducts.Values.
                FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ProductName.
                Equals(e.FormattedValue.
                ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                If p IsNot Nothing Then
                    key = p.ToString()
                Else
                    key = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
                End If
            Else
                key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
           Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                boundItem.Prp = Nothing
                boundItem.Prs = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRP").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRS").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

 Public Sub REFLECT()
        Dim bs = TryCast(BindingSource1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting))
        ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts.ToList().ForEach(Sub(m)
                                                                            For i As Integer = 0 To bs.Count() - 1
                                                                                If bs(i).ProductName = m.ProductName Then
                                                                                    bs(i) = m
                                                                                End If
                                                                            Next i
                                                                        End Sub)
    End Sub
    Private Sub setno()
        Dim i = 1
        Dim bs = TryCast(BindingSource1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting))
        For Each row As ProductFinaltesting In bs
            row.No = i
            i += 1
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                                If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)

                End If

                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
               If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                        boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                        dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                        boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                        dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                        boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                        dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
            setno()
        End If
    End Sub
 Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                    BindingSource1.AddNew()
                End If
            Else
            End If
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm As New formproduct
        AddHandler frm.Updated, AddressOf frmproduct_Updated
        AddHandler frm.FormClosed, Sub() RemoveHandler frm.Updated, AddressOf frmproduct_Updated
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frmproduct_Updated(sender As Object, e As formproduct.UpdatedEventArgs)
        Dim item = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, ProductFinaltesting)
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            item.ProductName = e.ProductName
            item.Unit = e.Unit
            item.Prp = e.Prp
            item.Prs = e.Prs
        End If
        BindingSource1.ResetBindings(False)
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ProductFinaltesting
    '<Browsable(False)>
    'Public Property Font As String = "☑️"
     Public Property No As Integer?
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Prp As Integer?
    Public Property Prs As Integer?
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName}"
    End Function

End Class
Public Class ProductFinaltestingService
    Private Shared Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test04102024.accdb;
                    Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    ' ...
    Friend Shared Function GetDistinctProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Friend Shared Function GetProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdateProducts(ByVal Obj As ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "UPDATE Products Set Unit=@Unit,Prp=@Prp,Prs=@Prs WHERE ProductName=@ProductName;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql, New With {
    Key Obj.Unit,
    Key Obj.Prp,
    Key Obj.Prs,
    Key Obj.ProductName
})
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

result update code

result update code 14102024


An event in formproduct can be raised and then handled by autocompledatagridview. When handling this event, update the datagridview.

@djv , Thank you for your response . you mean in formproduct in event BtnUpdate after line code loaddata() then autocompledatagridview >>should I make a public method or how can I please guide me

I don't get it. What's the use of the second Form? I can't see anything special about it. i.e. some parsing, validation...etc. Why not use one Form and set the Prp and Prs of the corresponding grid cells of the main Form? Not to mention, replacing a database product with another is a mistake. You're supposed to delete the old product (for a good reason and right user access) and insert a new one. No?

@dr.null , thanks for your response , What's the use of the second Form? >> formproduct Why not use one Form and set the Prp and Prs of the corresponding grid cells of the main Form? So this is what I want from the main form  autocompledatagridview This is actually as forminvoice specifically in DataGridView to save the record to the invoicedetail

@dr.null ,  Not to mention, replacing a database product with another is a mistake. You're supposed to delete the old product (for a good reason and right user access) and insert a new one. No? So the form database of the product is  formproduct (another form) and autocompledatagridview (Form main) is is the form for invoice details that I will use for the original project

@dr.null , autocompledatagridview (Form main) This is as a form transaction and form database is fixed i.e. formproduct. I can't see anything special about it. i.e. some parsing, validation...etc This is indeed not included in this post but if you want then I will update

@dr.null , You're supposed to delete the old product (for a good reason and right user access) and insert a new one. No? so I want to be able to update Prp and Prs from the second form or product form so that I can reflect or refresh to the main form without me having to retype if the h record is in the DatagridView row

Then just update the data source of the main Form instead of reloading data. Follow the answer below, implement the event to cast the bindingSource1.Current (main Form) to your model, update the model's properties from the UpdatedEventArgs (e.Prp, e.Prs ...etc), and refresh the view. Try.

@dr.null , Thanks for your reply. Then just update the data source of the main Form instead of reloading data. Follow the answer below, implement the event to cast the bindingSource1.Current (main Form)  you mean put this code bindingSource1.Current in Private Sub frmproduct_Updated

@dr.null , you mean like this Dim bs = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)) put in Private Sub frmproduct_Updated in autocompledatagridview (Form main). Please Guide me

@dr.null , then I have an error unable to cast object of type datagridviewcomplete.productfinaltesting to type system.componentmodel.bindinglist1[datagridviewautocomplete.productfinaltesting] then I change     Dim bs = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, ProductFinaltesting) but there are no errors and no reflection in the datagridview form main

@dr.null , I've updated in the update code post, maybe you can give some suggestions. DataGridView in mainform reflect when I do an update in the product form but try to call the same productname in the new row the value that appears in the prp is still the old one

The whole thing here needs to be rewritten. IIRC, according to your previous questions, it's possible that your database products table contains duplicate product names, but their units are different. The update condition (the WHERE clause) in UpdateProducts method specifies the ProductName field to instruct which records should be updated. Which means that all products with the same name will be modified. You must first repair your database. The records must be identified by an auto-generated unique id of type Integer.

@dr.null , Thanks for your reply. The whole thing here needs to be rewritten. you mean event CellValidating and CellValidated ok I'll update in this post . IRC, according to your previous questions, it's possible that your database products table contains duplicate product names, but their units are different. The update condition (the WHERE clause) in UpdateProducts method specifies the ProductName field to instruct which records should be updated.  For Productname there is no duplicate for the database now and the product name becomes the primarykey in the database

@dr.null , I've updated in the post update code full . Please Guide me.

Nope, ProductName can't be the primary key. Backup the database and execute a delete query. DELETE FROM [YourTable] WHERE ProductName = @ProductName or just ProductName = ? where the param = Adair. See what happens. I mean if we're talking here about this answer as base.

@dr.null , You are correct referring to the post but I have fixed the database there are no duplicates for ProductName

In frmproduct_Updated, cast Dim item = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, ProductFinaltesting), update its properties from e.xxx argument, and call BindingSource1.ResetBindings(false); to reflect the update. DO NOT repopulate the grids in both forms after add/edit/delete operations by calling that loaddata method. Only call it when you first time bind the data source.

@dr.null , Thank you for your response I have updated in the post frmproduct_Updated From your suggestion you make a result reflect update in the datagridview but I tried calling it in the next row of the datagridview with the same productname but the result in values that appear in PRS and PRP are still the previous ones. Please guide me

Try: item.ProductName = (New ProductFinaltesting() With { .ProductName = e.ProductName, .Unit = e.Unit }).ToString().

@dr.null , Thank you for your response. I updated in the post  in frmproduct_Updated With your recommendation but still at the time of calling the same item in the next row it still does not update but if I call this code  dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().     ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p) then the results are updated so Please guide and recommend from you

@dr.null , dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().     ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p) is it possible because this code has no binding datasource so BindingSource1.ResetBindings(false) has no effect? .

Right. You need to update the dictionary as well if you're changing the productname and/or unit to not be reverted/removed in the grid's validation events. If this works, then problem solved.

@dr.null , means the code in  frmproduct_Updated the solution is still I have to call again dictProducts so I can't do a reset via bindingsource.

@dr.null , I have the latest post and I used the answer code from your previous post maybe you can help me link

@dr.null , the code in frmproduct_Updated In the post is there anything I need to fix? please guide me  and if indeed this is the solution then I mark solved and receive the answer in this post

Nope, nothing to add. Good luck.

@dr.null , thanks. If there is no guidance from you then I can't solve this problem

@dr.null , I have a little problem , when in the mainform there are 2 items that are the same with different qty (quantity) I update from another form but the one that reflects is only the last row, you can see the last update gif file result update code 14102024. In main form frmproduct_Updated Please recommend or advise from you

Raise an event from the edit form which signals to the main form to update.
In formproduct:
Public Event Updated(sender As Object, e As UpdatedEventArgs)
Public Class UpdatedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public ReadOnly Property Unit As String
    Public ReadOnly Property ProductName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Prp As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Prs As Integer
    Public Sub New(unit As String, productName As String, prp As Integer, prs As Integer)
        Me.Unit = unit
        Me.ProductName = productName
        Me.Prp = prp
        Me.Prs = prs
    End Sub
End Class
Private Sub OnUpdated(e As UpdatedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Updated(Me, e)
End Sub

Inside formproduct.BtnUpdate_Click:
MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
loaddata() 
OnUpdated(New UpdatedEventArgs(txtUnit.text, txtProductName.Text, Prp, Prs))

Inside autocompledatagridview:
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    updateDataSource()
End Sub

' just to make a method that can be called from different places
Protected Sub updateDataSource()
    dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
        ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
    BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
    BindingSource1.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New formproduct
    AddHandler frm.Updated, AddressOf frmproduct_Updated
    AddHandler frm.FormClosed, Sub() RemoveHandler frm.Updated, AddressOf frmproduct_Updated
    frm.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmproduct_Updated(sender As Object, e As formproduct.UpdatedEventArgs)
    updateDataSource()
End Sub

You can also take the property from the UpdatedEventArgs and put it back in your main dgv to display the edited item. It looks like you know how to do that.

Thank you for your answer, I have posted the result of your answer, Like the gif file I posted I made 2 rows of datagridview blank after updating whether it is possible to reflect or refresh to an existing row datagridview autocompledatagridview without me having to retype
